# What constitutes a GitHub API call

Tags: git, github, limit

What essentialy constitutes a github api call. The documentation states that it has a limit on the number of api calls per hour. Does a call consist of any communication to the server like `push` or `pull`, or any git operation like `commit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any of the REST API endpoints listed in their [API v3 documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/) would count against the [API v3 rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting). There is also a [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/); using any of those endpoints would also count as an API call against the [API v4 rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/resource-limitations/).

It looks like the rate limits for the two APIs are unrelated: you could conceivably use both APIs to their respective limits in the same time span.

Regular `git` commands have [their own protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols). They would not count against your API rate limit as they don't use the API.